# How to replace chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged deprecated method?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to get data from the tab the user is leaving (switching on other tab or going on other program).

But chrome.tabs seems not providing an event allowing that..

Before there was apparently chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged (not tested) but it's deprecated.

And other event are giving the data of the new tab not the one the user just left...

I try also jQuery $(window).blur event, but i have to make a call to the chrome.storage of the tab left by the user (i create a storage for each tab named by the tab id) and i did not get the response of storage in time with this event (the result of the storage is used in a if() to know if i have or not to display an confirm box.

Someone could help me ?

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect a tab change, just use [`chrome.tabs.onActivated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated). Since you're interested in the previous tab, store the result of the event at the end of each event. For instance, like this:

```
var storedWindowInfo = {};
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    var windowLastTabId = storedWindowInfo[activeInfo.windowId];
    if (windowLastTabId) {
        // Do something with previous tab, e.g. send a message:
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(windowLastTabId);
    }
    // Update ID of currently active tab in the current window
    storedWindowInfo[activeInfo.windowId] = activeInfo.tabId;
});
```

Note: Only the tabID and windowID are provided to this event. You need to issue `chrome.tabs.query` to get more information, such as whether the tab still exists, its URL, etc.

Comment: Just, why the lastTabId is stored in the activeInfo.windowId ? It's not logical no ? Because i tried to get the activeInfo.tabId but was containing the id of the new tab... It will be clearer if the lastTabId was stored in a new property called like that in the activeInfo object ? No ?

Comment: I've created a dictionary `storedWindowInfo`. Each window has a "last active tab". I'm storing the ID of this tab as a value in the dictionary for later retrieval. Since a window is uniquely identifier by `windowId`, I use `windowId` as a key.